# JMS transactions in Tibco

Tags: jms, tibco

I know that a JMS message to a topic can be delivered to the same subscriber if the transaction rolled back. How can I achieve this in Tibco Designer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's basically two ways depending on what you want to achieve:

- via Acknwoledge mode: Use Client/TIBCO Explicit ACK mode in your JMS Topic Subscriber activity and after you executed your logic execute a confirm activity
- via Local JMS Transcation: use "Local Transation" in your JMS Topic Subscriber and after you executed your logic execute a confirm activity. This should be more suitable if any other JMS activities should be included in your processing that take part in the JMS transaction.

If there's an error in processing before you hit the confirm activity the message will be redelivered again. But note there might be some other factors in (e.g. settings on your TIBCO EMS or JMS server for redelivering  etc)

With best regards
         Sebastian